# very strange about unity3d www download path

Tags: web, unity-game-engine

I will use WWW to download file from local disk build of UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN version, because of the absolute download url path contains some special characters like chinese characters, so I want to use relative download path instead of absolute path. It's only ok at Unity Editor, but throw "can't find the file at Standalone version", anybody has ideal? thanks.

Comment: What did you use as relative path? Do you have a code example?

Comment: It's ok : string url = "Z:/MyAppRoot/1000.unity3d"; WWW www = new WWW(url), but if I use like this: string url = "./1000.unity3d"; WWW www = new WWW(url) int UnityEditor it's ok, but not standalone version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some confusing problems with loading files from local disk, too.
In your case, you try to load a file within the project folder, I guess. Thats why it works on UnityEditior but not on Standalone. The Standalone has not the same file structure.

Try to use

```
string url=Application.dataPath + "/../../1000.unity3d"
```

instead and save the file outside the project folder. And for the Standalone, save the file in the same folder as the Standalone executive.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use Application.dataPath, because of it contains chinese characters, but unity3d WWW doesn't support it, that's why I want to use only relative path